# How to print the whole column from resultset?

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to print the whole column from database using jdbc.
Created a arraylist "searchRes".
While running, I am just getting one row and not the whole column.

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    searchRes.add(resultSet.getString(1));

    for (String a : searchRes) {
        System.out.println(a + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use a `while` loop to continue until `resultSet.next()` returns `false`:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```